# Which http headers to suppress "This document is no longer available." on browser back button?

Tags: perl, http, firefox

A perl script creates a download page with this URL

```
http://server/cgi-bin/oursite/script.pl?action=checkme&username=myname
```

with headers set by:

```
my $q = new CGI;
...
print $q->header(-expires => '+0s');
```

with a bunch of links on it.  Here is one:

```
http://server/cgi-bin/oursite/script.pl?username=myname&action=retrieve&rmime=text__plain&rfile=HM_vmK9Ah.status
```

(That is the URL in an <A href="URL">filename</A> construct.)
If a user clicks on this link the target file is sent to the browser with headers:

```
  print "Content-type: $RMIME\n";
  print "Content-Disposition: inline\n\n";
```

Followed by the text of that file.  That displays as it should.  Unfortunately, if the user then attempts to use the browser's back arrow it fails.  Firefox (for instance), says this:

Document Expired

```
This document is no longer available.

The requested document is not available in the browser’s cache.

    As a security precaution, the browser does not automatically re-request sensitive documents.
    Click Try Again to re-request the document from the website. 
    [Try Again]
```

Clicking the "reload" button in the browser or "Try Again" in the message and then "resend" returns to the download page.

If the headers for the download page are instead generated by:

```
print "Expires: +0s\n";
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```

Then the "back" button works as expected.

I don't understand why the behavior differs in the two cases since other than the failure of the "back" button the pages are displayed the same (as text/html).  Can somebody please explain this?

A related question - if the browser is told to "show page source" on the download page created with the first header method that also brings up the "Document expired" message, and "Try again" "resend" shows the URL of the top page provided by the script.  However "show page source" on the top page immediately shows it, without the "Document expired" message.  If a page was created with the second header method then "show page source" does indeed show the source of the current page.  Again, why the difference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> print $q->header(-expires => '+0s');

This gets translated into `Expires: .. current date and time ..` which means that the response expires immediately. This means the result gets not cached and thus can not be displayed when going back in the browser.

> print "Expires: +0s\n";

This gets not translated but send as it is to the browser, i.e: `Expires: +0s`. Since `Expires` header expects an actual date and time which is not provided by you, this invalid header simply gets ignored and the default caching policy applies instead. This means that the page gets cached and can be  displayed when going back in the browser.

Comment: That makes sense.   Thanks.